# Gatsby not generating images from remote urls

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I have recently migrated from Gatsby v3 to v4 and doing so caused images to not be generated correctly.

I have a simple data structure that has an `imageUrl` which I am trying to create a node for and then I am trying to create the image with `createRemoteFileNode` ('gatsby-source-filesystem').

Example Repo: https://github.com/stretch0/gatsby-sandbox

// source nodes

```
const testNodes = [
  {
    name: "My Node 1",
    imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1665081661649-8656335a6cbb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1738&q=80"
  }
]

const sourceNodes = async ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }, options) => {

  testNodes.forEach((testNode) => {
    const node = {
      ...testNode,
      id: createNodeId(`myNode-${testNode.name}`),
    }

    actions.createNode({
      ...node,
      internal: {
        type: 'myNode',
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(node),
      },
    });
  })
};
```

// on create nodes

```
const { createRemoteFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

const onCreateNode = async ({ node, cache, store, actions: { createNode }, createNodeId }) => {  

  if( node.internal.type === 'myNode') {
    const myNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
      url: node.imageUrl,
      parentNodeId: node.id,
      createNode,
      createNodeId,
      cache,
      store,
    });

    if (myNode) {
      myNode.imageData___NODE = myNode.id;
    }  
  }
};
```

I am defining my schema like so:

```
module.exports = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;
  const typeDefs = `
    type myNode implements Node {
      id: String!
      name: String!
      imageUrl: String!
      imageData: File @link(from: "imageData___NODE")
    }
  `;
  createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

But when I try query the `imageData` via graphql it appears the image file hasn't been created. Am I doing something wrong / has something changed between v3 and v4?

[image]

Comment: Here's the migration guide: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-source-plugin-from-v3-to-v4/ but without a full context, I don't know exactly where the caveats are since I don't know what action or resolver are you using. I would start with the `createSchemaCustomization` where you should create the `sourceNodes`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but getting the same thing where the imageData is null in my query. It appears the `createSchemaCustomization` is all working correctly as the schema is correct. It's just the data being returned is not there.

Comment: @FerranBuireu I have pushed my code into a repo to give a more clear idea about what it's doing. It is a very striped back app just trying to retrieve the images: https://github.com/stretch0/gatsby-sandbox